# Potential vulnerability using PATCH method

Tags: php, laravel, http-patch

I am currently developing a web application in Laravel PHP framework to handle all the data input using HTML form.

Creating new entry in database is not an issue as it uses `POST` method, which the `ID` is hidden from the user, and there is validation on the server side.

However, when it comes to updating or modifying the entry in the database row, I am using the `PATCH` method to send the data to the URI `/form/{ID}`, for example `/form1/1`. I performed data and user validation at server side to prevent unwanted input from user. However, sometime some user with HTML knowledge can simply modify the `URI` of the form from `/form1/1` to `/form1/2` to `PATCH` the data to `ID=2` instead of `ID=1` which is counted as unwanted bypass.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening as this possess a potential security risk.

Comment: You would prevent this by simply checking that the owner of the data is the user that that subject data belongs to. if so the edit will take place, else   redirect.

Comment: other than validating the ownership of the data, is there any other validation I need to perform to further prevent the mentioned problem?

Comment: The title is completely misleading, it implies there's a vulnerability related to `PATCH` method. The vulnerability exists because you haven't implemented a check. If you do what @MattBurrow mentioned, then you're fine. To make this process trivial, you can utilize Laravel's middleware, which executes a route callback if a check succeeds.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the misleading title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Authorization. Take a look at the official documentation for more details https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Comment: I have the authorization, unless I verify the ownership of the data, user can simply `patch` to any `ID`

Comment: If you have authorization the user can update only his own posts.

Comment: Maybe he thought he has authentication. But yes, authorization should be implemented, try using security voters, this is how we do it in symfony projects.